# My function to convert decimal number into binary in (C) is producing wrong output for (some numbers)! [Without Arrays]

Tags: c, function, binary, decimal

I have a function that is supposed to convert a decimal number into binary.
The thing is for some numbers it works like the output for:

27 = 00011011

but for 5015 it converts it into 82630143 instead 1001110010111

This is my function:

```
int dec(int num) {
    long bNum = 0;
    int remNum, i = 1, highNum = 32768;
    while (num != 0) {
        remNum = num / highNum;
        remNum = num % 2;
        num /= 2;
        bNum = bNum + remNum * i;
        i = i * 10;
    }
    return bNum;
}
```

Any help would be really appreciated.

Comment: `1001110010111` is way to big to fit into an `int`.

Comment: @mch I've tried unsigned long and still the output wrong the only difference made was instead of the negative value, it produced positive!

Comment: Your function is not converting a decimal number into binary.  Numbers are neither decimal nor binary.  Numbers are `int`s, `long`s `float`s, `double`s, etc.  It is the ***human-readable representation*** of a number which might be decimal, binary, etc.  And that's usually a string.  So, a function which accepts an `int`, and supposedly converts it from one base to another, but also returns an `int` is completely ill-conceived.

Comment: Sorry @MikeNakis I meant my function is supposed to convert an integer into 16-bit binary...

Comment: @MrYosuko this does not make sense either. You probably did not understand my comment above.  Your function is not even trying to do what you think it does, and I am not sure you have a grasp of what you want it to do. Your description of what you are trying to accomplish does not make sense.  A function which converts an int to 16-bit is as follows: `int to16bit( int a ) { return a & 0xffff; }`

Comment: @MikeNakis I see. I didn't know that. I'm new at programming.
Thank you for showing me

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should check which of your variables don't have enough
"space" for storing your numbers.  I checked and see besides `bNum` your other variables like `i` don't have enough space:

```
unsigned long long int dec(int num) {
    unsigned long long int bNum = 0,i = 1;// i should be unsigned long long
    long int remNum,  highNum = 32768;//highNum is better to be long int 
    while (num != 0) {
        remNum = num / highNum;
        remNum = num % 2;
        num /= 2;
        bNum = bNum + remNum * i;
        i = i * 10;
    }
    return bNum;
}
```

and in your `main` check where you store returned number:

```
int main()
{
    unsigned long long int r;
    int a;
    scanf("%d", &a);
    r = dec(a);
}
```

Comment: @MrYosuko your welcome. Most likely your problem was because of `i`,  with debuggers you can see for yourself when and why something like this happens and find problem source and solve it.

Comment: Where is the need of  `highNum = 32768` and  `remNum = num / highNum;`?

Comment: @Holger I don't know too ,what is use of `remNum = num / highNum` 
 and so `highNum = 32768` to convert a decimal number into binary ,but since they were in original code they might be for something else(that I don't know) so I didn't remove them.

Answer (score 2):

As `mch` commented `1001110010111` is way to big for a integer. You can try to save it in a `unsigned long long int` variable, but actually the best way is to use a char-array or a char-pointer.

Comment: I just did that and the conversion is still wrong for decimal numbers above 1023

Comment: Well, if `bNum` is `unsigned long long int` it should have enough "space" to store the converted number.